# How to call a function from js module on browser console

Tags: javascript, selenium, module, recaptcha

I am trying to call a function from my browser console. But every time I try, the console returns me an error message.

But I am able to reach that function via another function here it is:

[image]

as you can see the function is called "onCaptchaSubmitted"

This is what happens when I try to call it from the console:

[image]

Finally, this also shows how that function implemented:

[image]

I do not know how to call that function. There must be a way to call it directly but how?

Thanks for your help..

Comment: The bundled code most likely runs within its own function scope. So unless you explicitly bind the function you want to call to the window object, then you can't call it.

Comment: @Olian04 then how can I bind that function ?

Comment: Depends on your exact setup, but this works in general `window.onCaptchaSubmitted = onCaptchaSubmitted;`

Comment: @Olian04 it will work, but `onCaptchaSubmitted` has `this` inside. That can cause problems...

Comment: @Anton actually it didn't work

Comment: @AhmetAzizBeşli what do you mean? You could not attach function to window as Olian04 told you? Or you've done it, but running it causes some problems?

Comment: @Anton window.onCaptchaSubmitted = onCaptchaSubmitted; didnot work because I'm already not able to reach that function from the console. It says the function is not defined.

Comment: @AhmetAzizBeşli oh, come on! You've told us: `I am able to reach that function via another function`, so just put `window.onCaptchaSubmitted = onCaptchaSubmitted;` to the place where you can see the function

Comment: @Anton I am able to reach it by **___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0].J.J.callback** but this "J.J" letters changes all the time (randomly) and It is not good for my crawler. That's why I was looking for another solution like importing or so on

Comment: @AhmetAzizBeşli we do not see your code (only images), but Olian04 has a good suggestion: the function is created and visible only inside its scope. Even if you will access it from the outside, you will need to pass a `this` to it (need code analyze and reverse engineering)

Comment: Might not be what you want to hear but captchas are designed to stop robots. Lots of smart people got together to I make this as complicated as possible by design. I've even seen sites have other anti-automation solutions after captchas.. I'm Not saying it's impossible but you're going to be facing an uphill struggle to get it working (sorry)